# Column graph with multiple grouped values and one value above all of them as goal and with filled space between

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I wish to create some kind of a special chart. I have 4 values, 3 are values measured over 3 years for state and the 4th is the goal where should it all go in future. The chart I want is a column chart with these 3 values grouped per state and the 4th to be above all of them as a line, with the space between the 3 values and the goal filled in.

Is something like this ever possible in excel 2007?

I will include a [picture](http://s22.postimg.org/zceddj4cx/explain.png) of what I want (sorry for poor quality)

[image: SU582721 example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Stacked Column for the yellow, blue and purple bars and the green "background" (ie the additional values that with your three values each add to (here) six. [Select 3x2 array.]  Then carefully insert a Shape (Line) where required and choose red for the line colour and increase its width to suit:

[image: SU582721 example]

Adjust the separation of the columns with Format Data Series > Series Options> No Gap.

Comment: Instead of inserting a Line shape to create the "goal" line, you could add a third data column with a constant value to get the "line" width you desired (for your example, each of the data points in the new column would need to be 1). This would eliminate the need for handwork.